# accessing at home windows network drive

Tags: networking, drive

I'm very new to ubuntu so I'm still very much stumbling around. In the file drawer I can see an icon for my network drive but I cant figure out where I enter or store the user id and password that this network drive has on it. The network drive is a windows based device

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I like doing this in CLI so what I would do is:

`sudo apt-get install samba samba-common samba-common-bin cifs-utils`

`sudo nano /etc/fstab`

Add this line at the end:

`//IP_address_of_file_server/path/to/your/files /path/to/mount/point    cifs    rw,username=username,password=password,uid=1000,gid=1000    0   0`

Set uid and gid numbers to match the ones of your Ubuntu user (you) on your machine. Command `id` can help with determining what they are. Also change the username and password to match your credentials for Windows share.